# Создание двумерного массива\матриц с пользовательской размерностью

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Задача в целом состоит в создании двух матриц с пользовательской размерностью. Однако главной проблемой для меня является синтаксис двумерных массивов, кои нельзя *(по моим скудным познаниям)* ассоциировать и создавать, основываясь на пользовательских переменных.

В С++ ещё до уровня чайника далековато, с указателями знаком очень поверхностно. Не могли бы в теории рассказать, какие статьи можно рассмотреть, или какие есть подручные методы решения проблемы?

p.s. - Никаких ограничений по методам нет в принципе, то бишь в теории это можно сделать и группой одномерных массивов, но мне это представляется более замудрённым.

Comment: Вектор векторов? `std:vector`

Answer (score 0):

Итак, матрица `NxM`... Пусть для определенности - целых чисел (`int`).

Вариант первый, самый плюсовый :) -

```
vector<vector<int>> A(N,vector<int>(M));
```

Семантика обращения стандартная - `A[i][j];`

Вариант второй, почти C'шный :)

```
int ** A = new int*[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) A[i] = new int[M];
```

Обращение такое же.

Вариант последний - создание класса с массивом из `NxM` `int`'ов, и переопределение оператора `[]` - вот *наброски*:

```
class Matrix
{
    Matrix(size_t N, size_t M):N(N),M(M), data(new int[N*M]){}
    ...
    int * operator[](size_t row) { return data + row*M; }

    size_t N, M;
    int * data;
```

Тогда опять же семантика обращения будет стандартной.
Вопросов выхода за границы диапазона, освобождения памяти во втором и третьем вариантах или необходимости константных и неконстантных версий в третьем - не касался, набросал только идейно, как это реализовать.